# uninitialized constant Mongo::Connection

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am using `rails 4.1.8` along with `ruby 2.1.2p95` and `mongo-2.0.4` gem on ubuntu machine to connect from some controller (X) in rails to `mongo db v3.0.3` . I have tried both the combination of code given below as suggested by many people. But i am getting the similar error in both the case:

```
 require 'mongo'
 include Mongo 

def mongocon
    @db = Mongo::Connection.new("192.168.56.102", 27017).db("convoos")
    #@db = MongoClient.new("192.168.56.102", 27017).db("convoos")
end
```

Error :

```
 uninitialized constant Mongo::Connection

 uninitialized constant WorkdbController::MongoClient
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using the new Mongo 2.0 driver which breaks backwards compatibility with the 1.x series. The code you are trying is for the 1.x series.

You simply need to do

```
require 'mongo'
db = Mongo::Client.new([ '192.168.56.102:27017' ], :database => 'convoos')
```

Here is the [tutorial for the 2.x version](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/) of the Ruby Mongo Driver.